# How to see full path value under ellipsis of Xcode Build Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, build-settings, search-path

could  anyone  help me how to see full value under Xcode Build Settings . 
in may case, it is search paths I could not see all full string, value  only shows ... (ellipis)

[xcode_build_search_path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2avF.png)

When I double click it only shows $(inherited) , I would like to see full resolved path  in Build Settings Editor itself. I researched but couldn't  figure out how to do it.
thank you !